# using the fql code with fb.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hey guys i am new to javascript  facebook sdk and am trying to generate the photos on the profile picture album.

when i researched about it i see the code `https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile"&access_token=...` which solve my solution..

Since am new to javascript i dont know where i want to add this ..But i have coded something like this

```
FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile"&access_token=', function(response) { #somecode } );
```

But this doesnt give me any output ..The question is where i want to add the line `https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile"&access_token=..`.

Is it on `FB.api` path section ?..Hope you guys can help me out in understanding this ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/ You need to omit the `https://graph.facebook.com/me` part to make it work:

```
FB.api("/fql?q=select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type='profile'", function(response) { #somecode } );
```

Comment: Thanks it was the one i needed brah ..:D

Comment: surely i will accept ..but i have a doubt i have added fb.login() method and add scope ..but when i tried to acees the app its not showing the scope which i have mentione in login..whyis it like that ..do i need to change the scope permissions on the app settings ?

Comment: That's another question. If you're using Graph API v2.0 with a non-admin user, you need to get your extended permissions reviewed by FB first before you can use them.

Comment: so firstly it needs to be reviewed by the facebook right ??

Comment: Please read the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login You should be able to use the permissions with the admin of the app to test it. For other users your app needs to be reviewed first.